# how do I store some bits in elastic search without any indexing?

Tags: java, json, database, elasticsearch

I am storing some documents in elastic search with 2 columns:

```
id     | data
---      -----
(int)    json string
```

What mapping do I use to ask elastic search to just store the json string without doing any processing on it? For efficiency, I do not want that column to be indexed or searchable - just want ES to store it as bits.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`"index": "no"`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2) in your mapping for that field.

So maybe something like:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "id": {
               "type": "integer"
            },
            "json_string": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "no"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```